# How to find the total number textbox in a web form using Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to find total number textbox present in a web form using Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form :text').size();
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').length;
```

Or there is filter selector `:text`

```
$(':text').length;
```

**More Info:**

- [`:text` selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)
- [Attribute Contains Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var total = $(':text').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need all the text-field in the page:

```
$(':text').length;
```

If you need all the text-field in the form:

```
$('form :text').length;
```